# Почему не инициализируется переменная?

Tags: kotlin

Повторяю урок из видеокурса и столкнулся с проблемой, не инициализируется переменная `shop`.
Хотя выше ей должен быть присвоен один из 2 объектов, в зависимости от того что выберет пользователь, в видеоуроке код компилируется без проблем хотя сделано все так же. В чем проблема?

[image: скрин]

код:

```
fun main(){
val moscowCoffeShop = MoscowCoffeShop(100,120,90)
val saintPiCoffeShop = SaintPiCoffeShop(110,130,100)
val shop: CoffeShop

println("Здравствуйте, пожалуйста выберите город:")
println("1. Москва\n2. Санкт-Петербург")

when (readln()) {
    "1" -> shop = moscowCoffeShop
    "2" -> shop = saintPiCoffeShop
    else -> println("Error")
}

println("пожалуйста выберите напиток:")
println("1. Американо\n2. Капучино\n 3. Латте")

when (readln()){
    "1"-> shop.makeAmericano()
    "2"-> shop.makeCappucino()
    "3"-> shop.makeLatte()
    else -> println("Error")
   }
}
```

Comment: По первому else надо не просто писать ошибку, а выходить из функции или кидать исключение

Comment: В первом readln получается, если не 1 и не 2, то shop будет не инициалиирован

Comment: Чему равен shop, если пользователь ввёл 3?

Comment: как сделать подскажите

Comment: Что именно сделать?

Comment: Пересмотрите внимательнее код на скриншоте видеоурока, там может скрываться какой-нибудь нюанс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в первом `when` при неправильном вводе просто выводить ошибку, но не прерывать программу, то дальше у вас переменная `shop` окажется неинициализированной. Нужно добавить прерывание работы функции с помощью `return`:

```
when (readln()) {
    "1" -> shop = moscowCoffeShop
    "2" -> shop = saintPiCoffeShop
    else -> {
        println("Error")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: да, сделал уже как советовали в комментариях, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
   shop = when (readln()) {
        "1" ->  moscowCoffeShop
        "2" ->  saintPiCoffeShop
        else -> return 
    }
```

компилятор не ругается теперь